# no Calendar icon for Vue-Bootstrap b-form-datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

How exactly do I get rid of the calendar icon for the `b-form-datepicker` in Vue
[image]
I've tried styling with

```css
.bi-calendar {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

but this only works if the style is not scoped, but I need scoped style.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you also tried

```css
.bi-calendar {
    display: none; 
}
```

or

```css
.bi-calendar {
    text-indent: -999999px; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work either